# Problem with displaying c ++ result & Wrong calculation result

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble getting the result of showing looking for numbers that match the equation.
Kind of calculations and all these data are correct, however, it now shows me 0 and 16 as inequality1
and inequality2. Does anyone have any idea, or a hint, what I'm doing wrong, or is it right? o_o

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int LW = 20, LK = 30;
char tab[LW][LK]; // tablica globalna tab[x][y]

void pokaz_tab(int& nierownosc1, int& nierownosc2)
{
    // int nierownosc1, nierownosc2;
    cout << nierownosc1 << endl;
    cout << nierownosc2 << endl;
}

void rozwiazanie_tab()
{

    int nierownosc1, nierownosc2;
    for (int y = 0; y < LW; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < LK; x++) {
            nierownosc1 = (pow(x - 13.0, 2.0) + pow(y - 10.0, 2.0) <= 64);
            nierownosc2 = (y < 1.15 * x);
            if (nierownosc1 && nierownosc2)
                tab[y][x] = '#';
            else
                tab[y][x] = '+';
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int nierownosc1, nierownosc2;
    rozwiazanie_tab();
    pokaz_tab(nierownosc1, nierownosc2);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure but what's the condition in this ```if(nierownosc1 && nierownosc2)``` suppose to do?

Comment: generally sorry for Polish words. It is about the simultaneous search for the result if 1 inequalities and the second is satisfied in finding the appropriate numbers in the loop.

Comment: You're printing two indeterminate values - your variables in `main` are uninitialized - and that has undefined behaviour. You might want to read about scope in your favourite C++ book.